# StarScream websocketDidReceivePong is not getting called for writePing

Tags: ios, websocket, keep-alive, starscream

I would like to send periodic pings to server to keep the connection alive.

This is the function to send ping

```
socket.writePing(NSData())
```

But I am not getting the pong back

```
func websocketDidReceivePong(socket: WebSocket){
    wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n websocket received pong")
}
```

the above delegate will get fired when server sends back the *pong*.

FYI:
I am able to successfully establish web socket connect send message and close connection and I have implemented and I have given `socket.delegate=self`

```
WebSocketPongDelegate
```

Here is the web socket url that I am using for testing purposes

> ws://echo.websocket.org/

I am wondering why I am not getting the pong back from web socket server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your socket a property of your class to make sure it sticks around? If you allocate it just on a function stack it will fall out of scope and the delegates will never get called. Also the `pongDelegate` is separate from the regular delegate, so you need to set that to self as well:

`socket.pongDelegate = self`